# Making a multi-line select box read-only in HTML

Tags: html, forms

Is there a way I can make an HTML multiple select box read-only? I want to have the scrolling capability, but I don't want to allow selections to be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out right after I posted -- The correct way of maintaining scrolling functionality while disabling selection is to disable each option:

```
<select MULTIPLE name="WG_Emp_List" class="mainText" readonly="readonly">
     <cfloop query="Agent_List">
        <cfoutput><option disabled>#LAST_NAME#, #FIRST_NAME#</option></cfoutput>
     </cfloop>
</select>
```

Comment: `disabled` removes the select from the form scope on submit so if you actually want the selected values, remember to remove disabled after submit() validation (assuming jQuery and adding id="WG_Emp_List" attribute to the select): `$("#WG_Emp_List option").prop("disabled",false)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="this.selectedIndex = 1">  
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>  
    <option value="Bar" selected="selected">Bar</option> 
</select>
```

You can read about it [here](http://techeyes.blogspot.com/2007/11/making-html-select-readonly.html).

Comment: Doesn't address Charlie's original request for MULTIPLE (although it does work for single select).