# Scrolling select element jumps to top when removing options from DOM in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

This issue appears to be isolated to Internet Explorer:

I'm moving `option` tags from one `select` to another when they're double clicked using Javascript. The `select` elements can have many items, so I've set the height with `overflow: auto;` so that they scroll. If you scroll down the list and double click an item to move, the `select` list will scroll up to the top when the `option` is removed, instead of staying at the current scrolled-to position as it does in Chrome or Firefox.

I made a basic example to demonstrate this here: https://jsfiddle.net/yk8LeLbw/1/

The Javascript is pretty simple:

```
 $(".listBoxSelectorAvail").dblclick(function() {
     $(this).find("option:selected").remove().appendTo(".listBoxSelectorAssigned");
 });
 $(".listBoxSelectorAssigned").dblclick(function() {
   $(this).find("option:selected").remove().appendTo(".listBoxSelectorAvail");
 });
```

I haven't been able to find any specific reason why this happens - I'm not sure if it's a bug or if this is expected behavior, but is there anything that can be done?

EDIT: made the title more clear

EDIT 2: I was hoping to *stop* the scrolling, but the best solution I've come up so far is to rescroll once the item has been moved, as seen here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yk8LeLbw/2/

Comment: I'm using IE 11 and it seems to work as intended.

Comment: Interesting - I'm using IE11 as well and it jumps to the top of the list for me.

Comment: "...the list the selection was made from jumps up to the top in Internet Explorer, instead of holding it's place..." - What exactly does holding its place mean? It won't _hold its place_ because it's removed and appended to another list.

Comment: @Brett Sorry I didn't explain this clearly: I mean that that when you scrolling down in the `select` element and double click an item that the `select` scrolls back to the top of the list instead of staying at the scrolled-to position it was at. Updating the question.

Comment: the scrolling elements scroll to the top for me too in ie 11

Comment: Oooh, _now_ I understand what you're asking.

Comment: IE behaves differently. Browsers are like snowflakes, no two are alike. You may have to wrap the `select` in a `div` and use some CSS rules to let the `div` control the scrolling. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044799/vertical-scrolling-of-disabled-select-mutliple-element-not-working-in-ie).

Comment: @Brett Good link, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that IE behaves differently. So, we have to work around that unwanted behavior. The solution is to wrap the `select` in a `div` and use some CSS.

Here's a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk8LeLbw/3/).

> Note how I wrapped a `div` around each `select` and replaced the `size="50"` attribute with the `multiple="true"` attribute. This removes the scrollbar on the `select` elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr1 = [];
  var arr2 = [];
  arr1.push("<div class='scroll'><select class='listBoxSelectorAvail' multiple='true'>");
  arr2.push("<div class='scroll'><select class='listBoxSelectorAssigned' multiple='true'>");
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    arr1.push("<option value=\"" + i + "\">Option " + i + "</option>");
  }
  arr1.push("</select></div>");
  arr2.push("</select></div>");
  $("body").append(arr1.join(""));
  $("body").append(arr2.join(""));
  $(".listBoxSelectorAvail").dblclick(function(e) {
    $(this).find("option:selected").remove().appendTo(".listBoxSelectorAssigned");
  });
  $(".listBoxSelectorAssigned").dblclick(function(e) {
    $(this).find("option:selected").remove().appendTo(".listBoxSelectorAvail");
  });
});
```

> Here's the modified CSS.

```
select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I like this better than forcing the rescroll - only problem I see is that the `multiple="true"` would allow for multiple selections rather than one at a time. This isn't in my fiddle, but I'm actually displaying information below the `select` elements based on the current selection, so this causes a bit of an issue for my specific case. Regardless I think it's the best solution, thank you!

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it. You could use some jQuery to enforce that only one element is selected. Modifying `select` style and behavior across all browsers is notoriously difficult. That's why many UI frameworks simply construct their own dropdown lists from `div`'s and `input` boxes instead of `select`'s.

Comment: Yeah, the situation isn't ideal but I think it's as good as it gets. I'm using jQuery UI in my solution, I'll check to see if there's anything there that may accommodate this better.