# IE. Disabled via property "disabled" <Select> blocks scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

When I try to disable "select" element, scrollbar of said  is becoming disabled, too, in Internet Explorer. In Chrome and Firefox, scrollbar is functioning perfectly. Is there a workaround for this issue?

```html
<select size="5" style="height:100px" disabled>
  <option>value 1</option>
  <option>value 2</option>
  <option>value 3</option>
  <option>value 4</option>
  <option>value 5</option>
  <option>value 6</option>
  <option>value 7</option>
  <option>value 8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It can't. If you want the users to be able to scroll then use `readonly` attribute and change the appearance using css.

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/25044799/6572922

Comment: Is your select dropdown is multiselect ?

Comment: @rahul_m yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
<div class="test" style="height:100px;width:65px;overflow-x:hidden;">
 <select size="5" multiple disabled>
    <option>value 1</option>
    <option>value 2</option>
    <option>value 3</option>
    <option>value 4</option>
    <option>value 5</option>
    <option>value 6</option>
    <option>value 7</option>
    <option>value 8</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Purely on select, it won't work, so I hope alternative may help your problem solve.

Here is working IE link of [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ET44/177/)